# Why does this code introduce hiss/noise into wave sequence

Tags: c++, audio, wav, file-conversion

I'm trying to extract PCM wave sequences from different files (files that are NOT audio files but contain audio data, and other data all in one file), and while this code does extract the expected audio, it seems to introduce a very audible hiss/noise into the sequence.

I've tried to find similar topics but the only thing I came across was either "*aliasing*" or "*dither*"? I've tried this code with a bunch of different files and formats, and it seems to add the same hiss noise into everything, so the hiss is definitely not contained in the original files that I'm trying to extract data from.

I know the original files contain **MONO 16bit 48Khz PCM** data.

```
int main()
{
const int               lenght  = 180; //file length, just a "long enough" number to make sure there's enough space for the whole sequence from the original file

const unsigned short    bits    = 16;
const unsigned int      bitrate = 48000;
const unsigned short    channels= 1;

std::ifstream file("samplesfile.img", std::ios::binary); //the original file that contains all sorts of data, plus a simple wave sequence

// Offset 1byte to align with the wave sequence bytes
unsigned int offsetAmount = 1;

if (offsetAmount > 0)
{
    unsigned char tmp[bits];
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(tmp), sizeof(unsigned char) * offsetAmount);
}


// Read everything from file after the offset and interpret it as a wave sequence
unsigned char* samples = new unsigned char[bitrate * lenght];
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(samples), sizeof(unsigned char) * bitrate * lenght);
file.close();


// creating a .wav file, calculating chunk data

unsigned short  PCM         = 1;
unsigned int    chunk1size  = 16;
unsigned int    chunk2size  = lenght * bitrate;
unsigned int    chunkSize   = chunk2size + 40;
unsigned int    byteRate    = (bitrate * channels * bits) / 8;
unsigned short  blockAlign  = (bits * channels) / 8;    



std::ofstream file2("res.wav", std::ios::binary);

if (file2.good())
{
    file2.flush();
    file2.write("RIFF", sizeof(char) * 4);
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&chunkSize), sizeof(unsigned int));
    file2.write("WAVE", sizeof(char) * 4);

    file2.write("fmt ", sizeof(char) * 4);
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&chunk1size), sizeof(unsigned int));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&PCM),        sizeof(unsigned short));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&channels),   sizeof(unsigned short));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bitrate),    sizeof(unsigned int));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&byteRate),   sizeof(unsigned int));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&blockAlign), sizeof(unsigned short));
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bits),       sizeof(unsigned short));

    file2.write("data", sizeof(char) * 4);
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&chunk2size), sizeof(unsigned int)); // 40 bytes up to here
    file2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(samples),     chunk2size);
}

file2.close();

delete[] samples;

return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You might load both the original audio file and the file your program output into Audacity together, so that you can compare the two waveform displays.  If your code is correct, they should be identical, but assuming it isn't, the visual differences between the two waveforms will probably be informative.

Comment: I've clarified my question, I'm tring to extract audio from files that are not audio files but do contain some audio hidden inside

Comment: My suspicion is that the original files' audio data isn't quite in the format you think it is; for example, they might be including one sample's worth of meta-data after each sample of audio data (interleaved) and your program is interpreting that meta-data as an additional audio sample, which would sound like distortion.   Audacity's waveform graph (ideally of a sine wave or similar) would make it pretty clear if that was happening.  (or they might be doing something really sneaky like encoding other data into the low-bits of their audio samples, and then masking it out on playback)

Comment: I'm starting to think that aswell, I just tried to use the same code to extract audio of a regular wave file with all the correct settings and there was no additional noise, so I'm assuming it's not the code that's wrong, it's my prediction for what's in the original file - it's probably what you're saying, I'll try to tinker with it tomorrow and report back :) thank you so far!

Comment: @JeremyFriesner has the right idea, but I would maybe go one further and try to simply write then extract 3 or 4 known audio sample values, like `-1` `0` `+0.5` or the equivalent (-2^15, 0, +2^14) for 16-bit PCM. You should then be able to write up a couple of tests that will help pin point if the data going in is identical and if it is being padded in any way.

Comment: So I've got back from work, I've had a look at the waveform that's produced after extraction, I've added the image to the original post (bottom) what do you guys think? I'm not seeing any pattern, the "spikes" appear at random rates/samples??!!